# When should a pointer be declared in the header file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, pointers

A question cropped up while watching a tutorial video.
Are there any rules regarding when to create a pointer in the header file or not?

E.g, let's say I want to create a new instance of a custom class in my ViewControllers viewDidLoad method.

Without a declaration of the pointer in the header file I won't be able to access it from outside this specific class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare any properties in your header file. Some objects like custom classes can only be referenced with a pointer there. When you want to use that object on more places then just locally you declare a pointer to that object. This is how you should use pointers in header files.

Just read up on how pointers are used,
For example here:
http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you declare it in the header file you can use the instance anywhere in that section, but if you declare it in somewhere in the .m you can only use it in that function. If you want the same names, but different variables in different functions you declare it in the .m